# How to select the last 5 records per group

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I am doing a query that looks at each part transaction within a certain time period.  Depending on the part, it could have maybe just 1 transaction or upwards of 1000 transactions.  I need to only pull the last 5 transactions per part.  Here is my query right without selecting only the last 5 transactions per part.

```
 SELECT     partnum, trandate, extcost
 FROM       parttran
 WHERE      trandate between '2012-05-15' and '2013-05-14'
```

I greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always useful in these situations: a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with a window function like [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  partnum, trandate, extcost,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY partnum ORDER BY trandate DESC)
    FROM    parttran
    WHERE   trandate between '2012-05-15' and '2013-05-14'
)
SELECT partnum, trandate, extcost FROM CTE WHERE rn <= 5
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help!  I am sorry to be a pain but when I try to run it its telling me: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '='.   I think it is talking about the = by rn=row_number().  Could you help me out with this?  Again, thank you for everything!

Comment: If you use at least SQL-Server 2005 it should work. However, since im on the road now I cannot show you an example.

Comment: simple mistake on my end, I added a field and didn't put an extra comma in!!  THANK YOU AGAIN!!!